# WebDriverException when I use NoraUI and Chrome web driver on my windows laptop

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver, noraui

I use NoraUI (Non-Regression Automation for User Interfaces) and Chrome web driver on my windows laptop and I have this big error stack trace. Yesterday, my code worked and I am sure I have not changed anything.

The below error appears when instanciating the Chrome selenium web driver on opening any URL:

```
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.58 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'ITEM-72885', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=d:\Profiles\sgrillon\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8244_3992}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=57.0.2987.133, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Session ID: 94defa860dff1660a2881b2d597ee974
  at noraui.application.steps.CommonSteps.<init>(CommonSteps.java:22)
  while locating noraui.application.steps.CommonSteps

1 error
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
            at cucumber.runtime.java.guice.impl.GuiceFactory.getInstance(GuiceFactory.java:42)
            at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
            at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:48)
            at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
            at ✽.Given I check mandatory fields:(steps/scenarios/RAPID-TRT-ASS.feature:5)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.58 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'ITEM-72885', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=d:\Profiles\sgrillon\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8244_3992}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=57.0.2987.133, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Session ID: 94defa860dff1660a2881b2d597ee974
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:882)
            at noraui.browser.DriverFactory.generateWebDriver(DriverFactory.java:153)
            at noraui.browser.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:57)
            at noraui.utils.Context.getDriver(Context.java:284)
            at noraui.application.steps.Step.<init>(Step.java:43)
            at noraui.application.steps.CommonSteps.<init>(CommonSteps.java:22)
            at noraui.application.steps.CommonSteps$$EnhancerByGuice$$60d24c4c.<init>(<generated>)
            at noraui.application.steps.CommonSteps$$EnhancerByGuice$$60d24c4c$$FastClassByGuice$$5ab45fbb.newInstance(<generated>)
            at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory$ProxyConstructor.newInstance(ProxyFactory.java:266)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
            at cucumber.runtime.java.guice.impl.GuiceFactory.getInstance(GuiceFactory.java:42)
            at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
            at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:48)
            at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)

com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.10 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'ITEM-72885', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=d:\Profiles\sgrillon\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4416_8177}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=57.0.2987.133, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Session ID: d187a933403bfcb6f6ca60d5d35a1df5
  at noraui.application.steps.CommonSteps.<init>(CommonSteps.java:22)
  while locating noraui.application.steps.CommonSteps

1 error
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
            at cucumber.runtime.java.guice.impl.GuiceFactory.getInstance(GuiceFactory.java:42)
            at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
            at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:48)
            at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
            at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
            at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
            at ✽.Given I check mandatory fields:(steps/scenarios/RAPID-TRT-ASS.feature:5)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.10 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'ITEM-72885', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=d:\Profiles\sgrillon\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4416_8177}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=57.0.2987.133, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Session ID: d187a933403bfcb6f6ca60d5d35a1df5
            ...
```

Would you have any idea about this issue ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Chrome update version automatically. You need update version of your Chrome Webdriver in :

> YourRobot\java\src\test\resources\drivers\windows\googlechrome\64bit\chromedriver.exe

with good version : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Example for version 2.29 => https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/

**EDIT for V4+:**

- check your Chrome version
- kill all webdriver process
- remove your local webdriver
- edit pom.xml

  - search your version on https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
  - copy version in `profile(preIC) > build > plugins > plugin(download-maven-plugin) > executions > execution(download-googlechrome-webdriverxxxx) > configuration > url`
  - search your ETag on https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.39/
  - copy ETag in `profile(preIC) > build > plugins > plugin(download-maven-plugin) > executions > execution(download-googlechrome-webdriverxxxx) > configuration > md5`
  - run robot

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. As @sgrillon said, you need to update your chromedriver.exe.
If you can't update the driver, then try to kill running chrome processes, and then retry.